# How to write async getter with Flutter/Dart?

Tags: java, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am creating an application in Flutter.
In this application, I need to call a library written in Java.
Now, the library, written in Java, has a getter and a setter for a property.
I want to call these getters and setters from Flutter/Dart, and we want to use it.

```java
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('com.example.java-library');

static Future<String> get versionCode async {
  final String versionCode = await _channel.invokeMethod('getVersionCode');
  return versionCode;
}

static set versionCode(final String code) {
  _channel.invokeMethod('setVersionCode', code);
}
```

However, if I write code like the above, I will get a warning at runtime.

```
The return type of getter 'versionCode' is 'Future<String>' which isn't assignable to the type 'String' of its setter 'versionCode'.
Try changing the types so that they are compatible.
```

How can I avoid the problem so that the warning does not appear?

Comment: I faced the same issue, do you have a solution?, this happens when im update dart sdk

Answer (score 1):

Would be better to use methods like so:

```
static Future<String> getVersionCode() async {
  final String versionCode = await _channel.invokeMethod('getVersionCode');
  return versionCode;
}
```

```
static void setVersionCode(String code){
  _channel.invokeMethod('setVersionCode', code);
}
```

When you want to retrieve(use) the value:

```
Future<void> anyOtherPlace()async{
   final String value = await getVersionCode();
}
```

Comment: You have to await for it, invokeMethod is async so you must await it.